# Issue with filtering list of items

Tags: parse-platform

In my collection I have a column named `client`. When I get the whole list of items (without any filters), it returns **26 items** that have value for `client` column equal to `"foo"`. But as soon as I apply any filter (e.g. `client = "foo"`, or `client != "bar"`) I get **only 2 items** that have value for `client` column equal to `"foo"`.

Filtering works fine for all the other `client` values (e.g. `"bar"`, `"baz"`, etc).

The issue is reproduced both for API and Parse Core (website).

Comment: That's nice. You haven't asked a question. You also haven't told us anything about the data model, data types, code being used...

Comment: The question is obvious - how to fix that? The data type of `"foo"` is obvious too - String. Code doesn't mater, because the issue is reproduced everywhere including Parse website.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're doing on the Parse website to get these "wrong" results.

Comment: How about whitespace in some of those values? "foo" != " foo"

Comment: @Dehli 15 of "evelyn_iona" clients without filtering http://joxi.ru/BA049MEiVQZLAy and now 5 with filtering by equals to "evelyn_iona" http://joxi.ru/Rmzg9eGi5kw62O

Comment: @danh it doesn't seem so based on API response http://joxi.ru/ZrJqQN9hWGNwAj